# mapValues with Spark Cassandra Connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

I'm very new with Spark and Scala, and I'm using spark-shell accesing to Cassandra through datastax open source [connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector)

with this command:

```
sc.cassandraTable("keyspace","table")
  .select("gender","name")
  .mapValues(v => v.get())
  .lookup("Male")
```

and get this error:

```
error: value mapValues is not a member of com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow]
```

I don't know if this transformation is only for datastax enterprise; and I am not able to find more information about that.

More details:

- Java 1.8.0_151
- Spark 2.2.1
- Scala 2.11
- Cassandra 3.11.1

Comment: `mapValues` is applicable to [`RDD[Tuple2[_, _]]`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions), not any `RDD`.

Comment: but there is an RDD... com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD

Comment: It is not if it is `RDD`, but `RDD` of what. By example `RDD[Int]` - no `mapValues`, `RDD[(String, Int)]` - `mapValues` which takes `Int => U`

Comment: @JuanAntonioAguilar: What is the expected result from that command?

Comment: Thank you @user8371915, that's it... I don't cast types from Cassandra to Scala types.

Comment: @mrsrinivas the focus is to be able to work with RDD's from Cassandra query... and in this case, working with Pair RDD's, and the result would be count names of Male gender in Cassandra Table, although the command is a preliminary stage aimed to this result. I know there is mistakes, but I needed type conversion to going on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've solved by this way, using the comments in the question:

```
sc.cassandraTable[(String,String)]("keyspace","table")
  .where("gender = 'Male'")
  .select("gender","name")
  .map{case (k,v) => (v,1)}
  .reduceByKey{case (v,count) => count + count}
  .collect.foreach(println)
```

The key of the solution is the type conversion `cassandraTable[(String,String)]` between Cassandra Row and Scala types in Spark.

Thank you.